# Ruby on Rails Gem Installation Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

[image: Ruby on Rails i can't install rmagick gem. please help me.]

the above image is the output of the installation result.

Comment: detailed stack trace on the questions is preferred to images

Comment: To build native extensions one needs the [tag:c] compiler and/or build tools.

Comment: What's in the mkmf.log? Did you try to build the gem directly, like what is suggested in the error message?

Comment: would you please add the stack trace that will be helpful.

Comment: Setting up the rails environment  in windows machine is tough job, If you planning for rails development, people usually suggest Linux or Mac platforms to avoid the unwanted  platforms compatibility issues in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `ImageMagick` and then `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --source`

on Mac: `brew install imagemagick`

on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

If your are on Windows, you can try [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)